# Logback TimeBasedRollingPolicy current filename dateless

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm programmatically configuring a Logback RollingFileAppender with a TimeBasedRollingPolicy. It looks something like this:

```
    RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> rollingAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
    TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> policy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent>();
    policy.setContext(rootLogger.getLoggerContext());
    policy.setFileNamePattern(filePath + "/log.%d.txt");
    policy.setMaxHistory(90);
    policy.setParent(rollingAppender);
    policy.start();

    rollingAppender.setContext(context);
    rollingAppender.setRollingPolicy(policy);
    rollingAppender.setTriggeringPolicy(policy);
    rollingAppender.setLayout(layout.getLayout());
    rollingAppender.start();
    rootLogger.addAppender(rollingAppender);
```

Ideally, today's logs would be in log.txt, and previously rolled ones would be in log.%d.txt. As it is, even today's logs are in log.%d.txt. How do I get a separate log file name for the current day's logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rollingAppender.setFile("foo.txt");`. The active filename is the property of the appender and not the policy.

Comment: I had been doing this initially, but with that line of configuration added it was not obeying the rolling policy (multiple days of logs were being put into log.txt, no log.%d.txt were ever generated)

Comment: Double check your code then. It works perfectly when given as XML config.

Comment: I tried it again, same exact code as in my original question, but I added `rollingAppender.setFile(filePath + "/log.txt")`.
Ran it once to generate log.txt file, set system clock forward a day, ran it again. The new logs just got appended into log.txt. No rolling

Comment: Well no, of course not. You can't test it by running it once, setting the system clock forward and running it again. You need to actually let the clock "roll" while it's running.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I guess I assumed incorrectly that it would roll if necessary on startup. But if I leave it running and change the system clock it does in fact roll in the way I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yup, no problem. It doesn't roll on startup because it doesn't know it should. It will assume that `log.txt` is the current day's log, even if clock has rolled.